# Exception in opening a socket at my IP address

Tags: c#, sockets, server

I am new in socket programming C#. I am trying to make a chat server between two computers but I am unable to do that because I cant start my Socket..... I gave the Server Program my IP address but gives me an exception... "The requested address is not valid in its context" ...Here is the code:

```
        IPAddress hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("178.189.27.85");
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(hostIPAddress, 8888);
        int requestCount = 0;
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
                string serverResponse = "Last Message from client" + dataFromClient;
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Client program

```
try {
        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

        tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.128.1",8888);
        // use the ipaddress as in the server program

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

        String str=Console.ReadLine();
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
        Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

        stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

        byte[] bb=new byte[100];
        int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

        for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

        tcpclnt.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
    }
```

Comment: Use the search. You must listen on an IP that the machine has assigned to any nic, and unless your modem is in bridge mode you have an internal IP address, most likely `192.168.x.x`. Just bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: `TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);` is redundant. Just declare the TcpClient later when you actually assign the variable `TcpClient clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IPAddress hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("178.189.27.85");
```

Is your computer actually on the public internet? I would expect your computer to have a private IP (eg 192.168.x.y, 172.16-32.x.y, 10.x.y.z) unless it is directly connected to your internet connection.

Assuming you're on Windows, use a Command Prompt and run `ipconfig`, or visit Control Panel and look for your network settings. On Windows 7 for instance it's in the Network and Sharing Center, under "Change adapter settings"; look for the active adapter, right click and choose "Status".

Once you find your local IP address, use that. Or you can use 0.0.0.0 as a wildcard address – in effect saying "Just accept connections from wherever, I don't care what my IP address is."

Comment: I used the IP from ip config now I am getting this exception on Client Program "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Comment: That's a different problem. Did you change your code to bind to 0.0.0.0? Or some other address? In your client program (which you haven't provided code for) are you running it on the same computer?

Comment: No I am not running it on the same computer.Its a different computer.... Above I have mentioned the Client program

Comment: From the "client" computer, ping your "server" computer. So if your server computer is 192.168.128.1, you would open Command Prompt and type `ping 192.168.128.1`. If you get "timed out" errors then you need to verify the IP address and network settings on these computers. It's a bit outside of the scope of this question, but you can open a new one.